# Python soup error

Tags: python

Hi guys this is my code:

```
#! /user/bin/env python
import os
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
string = os.system("curl -i https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coldplay")
soup = BeautifulSoup(string, features="xml")
tag = soup.find_all("tbody")
```

and when i will execute it this is my error

```
  enter code hereTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_wiki.py", line 6, in <module>
  soup = BeautifulSoup(string, features="xml")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
  TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

i'm beginner and i haven't a idea what is the problem sorry

Comment: `os.system()` doesn't return the output of the command, it returns the exit code, which is a number.

Comment: `os.system` returns the exit code of the command you ran, not a string of whatever that command printed.

Comment: `os.system` returns no data, just a numeric return code.

Comment: Thanks you guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system` will return the exit code of the command. Not the return data. If the command is ran successfully, `string` will be 0.

You should instead use `subprocess.call`:

```
subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-i',
    "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coldplay"
    ], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But you shouldn't use curl command when using python, use `urllib` instead:

```
import urllib.request 
url = "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coldplay"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), features="xml")
tag = soup.find_all("tbody")
```

if you're using python 2, do `import urllib2` and use `urllib2.urlopen` instead.

A more popular way over using `urllib` is to use the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, but you will need to install it, `pip install requests`.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coldplay')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="xml")
tag = soup.find_all("tbody")
```

Comment: Thanks you for say me step by step what i do.

Answer (score 1):

You were correctly told in the comments that `system` does not return the program output. But there is no need to use curl at all. Python module `urllib.request` works just fine:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
URL = "https://it.wikipedia.o‌​rg/wiki/Coldplay"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(URL), f‌​eatures="xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

To use curl, you need to import and run subprocess.check_output or subprocess.run (Python 3.5+ only) to capture the output of a system command. As stated already, os.system returns only the error status of the command you run, not its output,  which goes to console.

See this discussion:

[Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

There may be better ways to achieve your goal, but to understand how to make your existing code work, try subprocess.